# Using Sudo su in Overthere/sshj

Tags: java, ssh, remote-access, overthere

I've been attempting to use Overthere to access a remote box. The commands I want to run

```
sudo su - username
```

However the application hangs waiting for the password. Additionally I'm not sure how to enable logging to see what's going on.

Here is my code:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
    options.set(ADDRESS,"11.214.133.104");
    options.set(USERNAME,"user");
    options.set(PASSWORD,"password");
    options.set(OPERATING_SYSTEM,UNIX);
    options.set(CONNECTION_TYPE,SU);
    options.set(SU_USERNAME,"superuser");
    options.set(SU_PASSWORD,"password2");
    options.set(SUDO_PASSWORD_PROMPT_REGEX,"(\\[sudo\\]\\spassword\\sfor\\susername:)");
    options.set(ALLOCATE_PTY,"vt220:80:24:0:0");

    OverthereConnection connection = Overthere.getConnection("ssh", options);
    try {
        connection.execute(CmdLine.build("sudo - su superuser"));

    } finally {
        connection.close();
    }
    }
}
```

And my logback config:

```
<configuration debug="true">
<appender name="OVERTHERE" 
class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<file>log/overthere.log</file>
<rollingPolicy 
class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <FileNamePattern>log/overthere.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
</rollingPolicy>
<encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%logger{36}] %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!-- set the level to 'debug' or 'trace' for more details -->
<logger 
name="com.xebialabs.overthere.ssh.SshElevatedPasswordHandlingStream" 
level="TRACE">
    <appender-ref ref="OVERTHERE" />
</logger>
</configuration>
```

This is the output I get:

```
[sudo] password for username:
```

Comment: Do you want to be able to automatically send the password for after executing `sudo su - username` ?

Comment: Hi Gil, yes I do. Thanks.

Comment: Well I've gone back to Jsch and got that working. But out of interest it would be good to know how it works in over there.

Comment: Please have a look at this part of the documentation... https://github.com/xebialabs/overthere#sudo-and-interactive_sudo. You need to use interactive sudo to handle the password prompt.